# Entity Framework Core SQLite with Xamarin.Forms doesn't update Db

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xamarin.forms

I'm making a Xamarin.Forms MVVM App with an Entity Framework Core SQLite to save a Db locally in the mobile phone.

I generate the Db and some initial items, later through App I add a new item, for the moment it works fine (Refreshing the listview in App and showing all items correctly).

The problem is when I want update one item in the Db. I update the item but doesn't update in the listview. The only way that it updates in the listview is restarting de App.

**How can I refresh the listview with the updated item?**

## This is the Datacontext code:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base()
    {
        //Database.EnsureDeleted();
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public DbSet<Sensor> Sensors { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "database.sqlite")}");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Sensor>(s =>
        {
            s.HasKey(en => en.Id);
            //s.HasIndex(en => en.ClientId).IsUnique();
            s.Property(en => en.Name).IsRequired();
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Sensor>()
            .HasData(
                new Sensor { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ClientId = "11111", Name = "First item", Description = "This is a private item description.", Payload = "Off" },
                new Sensor { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ClientId = "11112", Name = "Second item", Description = "This is a shopping item description.", Payload = "Off" },
                new Sensor { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), ClientId = "11113", Name = "Third item", Description = "This is a work item description.", Payload = "Off" }
            );
    }
```

## This is the MainPageViewModel code:

```
    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    private readonly DataContext _dataContext;
    private static MainPageViewModel _instance;
    private DelegateCommand _addSensorCommand;
    private ObservableCollection<SensorItemViewModel> _sensors;

    public MainPageViewModel(
        INavigationService navigationService,
        DataContext dataContext) : base(navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _dataContext = dataContext;
        _instance = this;
        LoadSensors();
    }

    public DelegateCommand AddSensorCommand => _addSensorCommand ?? (_addSensorCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddSensor));

    public ObservableCollection<SensorItemViewModel> Sensors
    {
        get => _sensors;
        set => SetProperty(ref _sensors, value);
    }

    public static MainPageViewModel GetInstance()
    {
        return _instance;
    }

    private async void AddSensor()
    {
        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("SensorPage", null);
    }

    public async void LoadSensors()
    {
        try
        {
            var _sensors = await _dataContext.Sensors.ToListAsync();
            Sensors = new ObservableCollection<SensorItemViewModel>(_sensors.Select(s => new SensorItemViewModel(_navigationService)
            {
                Id = s.Id,
                ClientId = s.ClientId,
                Name = s.Name,
                Description = s.Description,
                Payload = s.Payload
            }).ToList());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Aceptar");
        }
    }
}
```

## This is the SensorPageViewModel code:

```
    public class SensorPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    private readonly DataContext _dataContext;
    private DelegateCommand _addCommand;
    private Sensor _sensor;
    private string _buttonText;

    public SensorPageViewModel(
        INavigationService navigationService,
        DataContext dataContext) : base(navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    public DelegateCommand AddCommand => _addCommand ?? (_addCommand = new DelegateCommand(Add));

    public string ButtonText
    {
        get => _buttonText;
        set => SetProperty(ref _buttonText, value);
    }

    public Sensor Sensor
    {
        get => _sensor;
        set => SetProperty(ref _sensor, value);
    }

    public override void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);

        if (parameters.Count >= 1)
        {
            var parameterSensor = parameters.GetValue<SensorItemViewModel>("Sensor");
            Sensor = new Sensor()
            {
                Id = parameterSensor.Id,
                ClientId = parameterSensor.ClientId,
                Name = parameterSensor.Name,
                Description = parameterSensor.Description,
                Payload = parameterSensor.Payload
            };
            Title = Sensor.Name;
            ButtonText = "Editar";
        }
        else
        {
            Sensor = new Sensor();
            Title = "Nuevo sensor";
            ButtonText = "Salvar";
        }
    }

    private async void Add()
    {
        if (ButtonText == "Editar")
        {
            ButtonText = "Salvar";
            Title = "Editar";

            return;
        }

        try
        {
            if (Title == "Editar")
            {
                _dataContext.Sensors.Update(Sensor);
                await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                Sensor.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                _dataContext.Sensors.Add(Sensor);
                await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", ex.Message, "Aceptar");

            return;
        }

        MainPageViewModel.GetInstance().LoadSensors();
        await _navigationService.GoBackAsync();          
    }
}
```

## This is the SensorItemViewModel code:

```
public class SensorItemViewModel : Sensor
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
    private DelegateCommand _selectSensorCommand;

    public SensorItemViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public DelegateCommand SelectSensorCommand => _selectSensorCommand ?? (_selectSensorCommand = new DelegateCommand(SelectSensor));

    private async void SelectSensor()
    {
        var parameters = new NavigationParameters
        {
            {"Sensor", this}
        };

        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("SensorPage", parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of SensorItemViewModel.cs also?

Comment: Added the `SensorItemViewModel.cs` and changed the `List<SensorItemViewModel>` to an `ObservableCollection<SensorItemViewModel>`. To refresh the `ListView` after update a value, but doesn't work.

Comment: You need to raise 'INotifyCollectionChanged' or you could use 'ObservableCollection' because it implements 'INotifyCollectionChanged'.

Answer (score 1):

I debuged the progrma flow and I found that when I update item and save the `_dataContext`in the `SensorViewModel` it doens't apear in the `MainPageViewModel`.

## Saving the update item in `SensorViewModel` I added `Actualizado` in the name:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## But when I read de `_dataContext` in the `MainViewModel` it doesn't apear:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

When I added a new item it work fine with out problems.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is not that Xamarin.Forms doesn't update the database. When you close and then open the app, you say that you can see the updated value. This means that the value has persisted successfully in the database. The problem is that the UI doesn't know that something has been updated. When you add/remove item from the **ObservableCollection**, then the collection takes care of that, since it raises **OnPropertyChanged** for you. However, when you simply update an item (change some of its properties) you need to tell the UI that something has changed. This is done via the **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/separate-your-ui-and-code-with-xamarin-forms-data-binding/5-exercise-implement-inotifypropertychanged) about the **INotifyPropertyChanged**

The simplest implementation is this:

```cs
public class PropertyChangedViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected void SetValue<T>(ref T backingField, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingField, value))
        {
            return;
        }

        backingField = value;

        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }
}
```

After that, you can have your `SensorItemViewModel.cs` inherit from the `PropertyChangedViewModel` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event when you need to.

Another thing - you should never subclass the database entity class with your ViewModel class. The idea of MVVM is totally different than to have the same class twice, sort of. Your `SensorItemViewModel` should have its own properties and for each property that you want to update dynamically in the UI, you need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event.

Let's say that you have only one property (**Name**) and you want to change it dynamically. Then your `SensorItemViewModel` will look like this:

```cs
public class SensorItemViewModel : PropertyChangedViewModel
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get => name;
        set => SetValue(ref name, value);
    }
}
```

Here, each time the `Name` property changes, it will invoke `SetValue` method, which will handle the event raising for you, which will notify the UI that the name needs to be changed/redrawn.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'm usin a Xamarin.Forms with a Prism Mvvm and after check the code I found that `OnPropertyChanged` is included in the `ViewModelBase`. I'm going to make a basic new project to try to find the mistake.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have it built-in. This is even better then. The solution here is to notify the UI that there is a change somewhere and then the UI will know what to re-render. Use the PropertyChanged in our new project and you will see an immediate update in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple App to show the concern.

The program use Entity Framework SQLite Xamarin.Forms and Prism with MVVM

This is the link to GitHub:

[Test EFSQLite](https://github.com/BullT/EF_SQLite_Test.git)